# I'm trying to add components relating to bets to my game in Java, but the program stops working after it asks for a bet amount

Tags: java, eclipse, methods, boolean

So I'm trying to make this car racing game, modeled after horse races. I've tested the game without the betting component and it works the way I want it to, so thats no problem. But once I started to implement the betting, the program kinda gave up on me. After the user is prompted to enter the bet, the program is just blank.

I'm not getting any error messages and I've tried debugging, but I just *really* can't figure it out.

I've attached the whole code minus the header; all it is is the names of the cars. (1,2,3)

```
public static void main(String[]args)throws IOException, InterruptedException{ //start main

    Scanner in;
    in = new Scanner(System.in);

    boolean doAnother = true;

    printHeader();
    printGame();
    while (doAnother) { //start while
        int response;
        System.out.print("\nWanna play again? 1 = yes, 2 = no.");
        response = in.nextInt();

        if (response == 1) { // start if loop
            doAnother = true;
            printHeader();
            printGame();
        } // end if loop
        else {
            doAnother = false;
            System.out.println("Come back again soon!");
        }

    } //end while look
} //end main

public static boolean printGame()throws IOException, InterruptedException{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rd = new Random();

    int car = in.nextInt();
    if (car >= 4) {
        System.out.println("THATS NOT AN OPTION! You automatically lose.");
    } else
        bet();
    System.out.println("Commence race!");

    Thread.sleep(250);

    int lambo = 0,
    nissan = 0,
    egg = 0;
    int track = 100;
    while (true) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            System.out.println();

        for (int i = 0; i < track; i++) {
            System.out.print("-");
        }
        System.out.println();

        lambo = lambo + rd.nextInt(4) + rd.nextInt(2) - rd.nextInt(2);
        nissan = nissan + rd.nextInt(4) + rd.nextInt(2) - rd.nextInt(2);
        egg = egg + rd.nextInt(4) + rd.nextInt(2) - rd.nextInt(2);

        for (int i = 0; i < lambo; i++) //L
        {
            System.out.print("."); //distance travelled
        }
        System.out.println("ℾ");
        //
        for (int i = 0; i < nissan; i++) //M
        {
            System.out.print("."); //distance travelled
        }
        System.out.println("ℿ");
        //
        for (int i = 0; i < egg; i++) //T
        {
            System.out.print("."); //distance travelled
        }
        System.out.println("⅀");
        //
        for (int i = 0; i < track; i++) {
            System.out.print("-");
        }
        System.out.println();
        //
        Thread.sleep(250);
        //
        if (nissan > track || lambo > track || egg > track) {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (car == track) {
        System.out.println("\nYour car won! Rad!");
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("\nYour car lost... bummer.");
        return false;
    }
} //printGame
public static void bet()throws IOException, InterruptedException{
    Scanner in;
    in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int money;
    int bet;
    boolean userWins = true;

    money = 100;
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("You have " + money + " dollars.");
        do {
            System.out.println("How much do you wanna bet? Or, enter 0 to walk away.)");
            System.out.print("$");

            bet = in.nextInt();
            if (bet < 0 || bet > money) {
                System.out.println("Your bet must be between 0 and " + money + '.');
            }
        } while (bet < 0 || bet > money);{
            if (bet == 0) {
                System.out.println("Bye.");
                break; //walk away
            } else {
                userWins = printGame();
            }
            if (userWins == true) {
                money = money + bet;
            }
            if (userWins == false) {
                money = money - bet;
                System.out.println();
            }
            if (money == 0) {
                System.out.println("Aw shoot, looks like you've are out of money!");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("You walk away with $" + money + '.');

} //end method
```

Comment: Do not know what I was thinking there lol....

Comment: Run your code step-by-step under debugger and you will see what's going on.  It's very easy with Eclipse.

Comment: @PM77-1 I've tried, but I'm still kind of new to programming so I don't quite understand exactly how to use the debugger tool- I dont know what I'm supposed to be looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two scanners nested like that. You must use the same scanner from the main method in you other methods or close that scanner

Comment: What do you mean? Like delete all of the scanners under all the methods and only keep the one under main?